# Why does Lord El Melloi II, at times, address his apprentice not by her name, Gray, but as Lady?

Tags: lord-el-melloi-ii-case-files

Most of the time, Lord El Melloi II just addresses his apprentice, Gray, by her name, but there are occasions where he refers to her as "Lady", similar to how Svin speaks of Gray as "Milady".
When and why does Lord El Melloi II address Gray as "Lady"?